# Core-audio - constructing an AudioBufferList struct (Q about c struct definition)

Tags: c, struct, core-audio

The definition of AudioBufferList looks weird to me… i guess my C is not so good

```
struct AudioBufferList
{
    UInt32      mNumberBuffers;
    AudioBuffer mBuffers[kVariableLengthArray];
};
typedef struct AudioBufferList  AudioBufferList;
```

Why

```
AudioBuffer mBuffers[kVariableLengthArray];
```

and not

```
AudioBuffer *mBuffers;
```

?

kVariableLengthArray appears to be == 1. Eh?

I think i have it working but would appreciate it if anyone could set me straight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the symbol `kVariableLengthArray` is a compile-time constant, this means that you can allocate a single buffer on the stack ("automatic" storage type, in C).

```
AudioBufferList single;

single.mNumberBuffers = 1;
```

Since the struct includes a count, it also means that you can create an instance with any number of buffers, like so:

```
AudioBufferList * get_n_buffers(size_t num)
{
    AudioBufferList *list;

    if(num < 1)
      return NULL;

    list = malloc(sizeof *list + (num - 1) * sizeof list->mBuffers[0]);
    list->mNumberBuffers = num;

    return list;
}
```

The latter code dynamically allocates an `AudioBufferList`, and relies on the fact that the array is last. So in memory, it will lookas if the `AudioBuffer` ends with the proper number of `AudioBuffer` instances, as the proper amount of space will be allocated.

Comment: Should that be 'malloc( sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (num-1)*sizeof( list->mBuffers[0]) );'? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @mustISignUp: no, I find it bad to repeat type names, and always prefer sizeof on expressions of the proper type. That way, if list were to change to a different pointer type, it would still do the rigtht thing. sizeof *list is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I absolutely believe you but can't grasp how 'sizeof *list' is enough memory for a struct AudioBufferList…

Comment: @mustISignUp: The variable "list" is of type "pointer to AudioBufferList", so the value of "sizeof *list" is the same as "sizeof (AudioBufferList)". If I had only said "sizeof list" it would be broken, it must be dereferenced to get the size of the object the pointer points at, i.e. AudioBufferList.

Comment: ok, i thought sizeof *list would be the size of the pointer, but of course it is the size of the object pointed to. Thanks for your help

Comment: I prefer using offsetof: list = calloc(1, offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers) + (sizeof(AudioBuffer) * num));

Answer (score 1):

```
AudioBuffer * mBuffers;
```

You are declaring a pointer to AudioBuffer
In such a case, you need to allocate enough memory, for instance with malloc().
Structures will be placed on the heap, and you will need to free the memory with free() after usage.

```
AudioBuffer mBuffers[ 1 ];
```

You are declaring an array of AudioBuffer. Memory is allocated automatically on the stack. No need to call free.

So when it's inside a structure, it's easier to work arrays, as you don't need to allocate memory explicitly to the structure member:

```
AudioBufferList myBufferList;
```

Otherwise, you would have to do:

```
AudioBufferList myBufferList;
myBufferList.mBuffers = malloc( sizeof( AudioBuffer ) * kVariableLengthArray );
/* ... */
free( myBufferList.mBuffers );
```

Comment: Sorry, i might be being stupid but i still don't get it. You're saying that 'AudioBuffer mBuffers[ kVariableLengthArray ]' allocates memory for 1 AudioBuffer?

Comment: It's an array, with only one element. But as the number of elements comes from a constant, maybe it will change in a future release. So declaring it in such a way leaves the possibility to have more AudioBuffers.